# Confusion over php sql and javascript time stamps

Tags: php, jquery, timestamp

I'm inserting time in iso format to a sql databse:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$datetime = new DateTime($now);
$now = $datetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$sql="insert now etc"
$pdo->execute
```

I found this nifty jquery plugin called timeago :
http://timeago.yarp.com/

```
//javascript
var statusTime = code to get info from sql databse 
$("#status").html(<time class="timeago" datetime="'+statusTime+'""></time>);
```

When I insert the data and look it up in the browser with the above code I get eight hours ago.

I don't really understand all the time formats that exist in web dev, can anyone point me in the direction of getting these two to sync?

Comment: Sounds like one of your code blocks isn't taking the time zone into account.

Comment: It may be worth checking that the timezone setting in php.ini matches the region that you're located in.

Comment: Well lets say in php.ini it is not, does javascript go to look at where I"m located, or the server?